# SQL return the rank of an item

Tags: sql

how to make a query that gets the rank of an item? (for azure database)

for example :

```
table name: studentScore

    studentName Scrore 
    student1      80
    student2      70
    student3      90
    student4      60
```

want to get the rank of student1, which is 2.

what I tried:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Scrore])AS Rank 
FROM studentScore where [name] = 'student1'
```

return

```
Rank
  1
```

I want

```
Rank
 2
```

Comment: select * from 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Scrore] desc)AS Rank, studentName FROM studentScore) t
where Name = 'student1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rank() or dense_rank() functions:

```
declare
    @t table (studentName varchar (100), Score int)

  insert into @t
  values 
    ('student1', 80),
    ('student2', 70),
    ('student3', 90),
    ('student4', 60)

    select rank() over (order by Score desc) rnk, * from @t

    select dense_rank() over (order by Score desc) rnk, * from @t
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: Added 'desc' for sort order

Comment: but it is not returning the student 1 rank.

Comment: @GabrielLam Studen1 has rank 2

Comment: right i know , but that is not what I want , i wanted it to return rank 2 , not the entire table.